# How to make the submit button call a function?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, function

```
<%= form_tag('add_person', method: 'get') do %>
                <%= label_tag(:name, 'Name') %>
                <%= text_field_tag(:name) %>
                <%= submit_tag 'Add new person' %>
        <% end %>

<%= def add_person
                if params[:name] == "John")
                enter code here
                else
                enter code here               
                end
end %>
```

How do I make the submit button call the function add_person? I'm using Ruby/Rails

Comment: why aren't you using the default update action?

Answer (score 2):

Calling one or more methods via submit button:

The form_tag helper determines the controller method to be called:

```
<%= form_tag('controller/controller_method', method: 'put') do %>
```

The submit_tag passes a value to the controller where it's evaluated.

```
<%= submit_tag "Add Person" %>
```

In the controller, you branch based on the value passed by your submit button:

```
def controller_method
  if params[:commit] == "Add Person"
    add_person
  elsif params[:commit] == "Method 2"
    method_2
  elsif params[:commit] == "Method 3"
    method_3
  end
end
```

Calling method via arbitrary button

You probably have something like this at the bottom of your form:

```
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

which can be replaced with the `button_to` helper, like so:

```
  <%= button_to "Submit", :method=> 'add_person' %>
```

Your `add_person` method would have to be defined in the controller for the object to which your form refers.

Comment: instead of f.submit (which is used for form_for), we will have submit_tag (used in form_tag presented in the question).